# ifconfig /displaydns doesn't work on Ubuntu 16

Tags: dns

I tried to check last sites which I visited recently typing `ifconfig /displaydns` in my terminal. Then an error occured: `/displaydns: error fetching interface information: Device not found`. Is it global problem or something is wrong only on my PC, if yes what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ifconfig /displaydns is a windows command not a linux one.
Man ifconfig shows no displaydns option.